# Usercontrol contains a combobox, but the Items set at design time are not in the run time

Tags: c#, windows, combobox, custom-controls, items

I have a user control that contains a textbox and a combobox. I have exposed the combobox's Item property to clients of the user control, thus:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection Item
{
    get { return baseComboBox.Items; }
}
```

I added the user control to a windows form, and set the Items list using the property values editor in the form designer. I then ran the application, and the combobox's drop down list was empty. To confirm that the items added at design time were not in the list, I added the following two lines of code to the  client form:

```
textBox1.Text = userControl1.Items.Count.ToString();
userControl1.Items.Add("Test item");
```

When I re-ran the application the test box showed a count of 0 (zero), and the drop-down list of the user control contained only "Test item".

Thinking that maybe the instance of the user control being referenced at design time is a different instance from that being referenced at run time, I set the user control's BackColor property at design time. When I re-ran the app, the user control's BackColor was what I had set it to in the designer.

Any ideas on why the design time setting of the Items does not carry over into the run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an attribute:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Item {
  get { return baseComboBox.Items; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the setter defined also, something like:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection Item
{
    get { return baseComboBox.Items; }
    set { baseComboBox.Items = value; }
}
```

Or, maybe it's because you are exposing **Item** but setting **Items**

Comment: Steve, thanks for the response. Note that "Item" was a typo, and it doesn't really matter what the property name is, as long as the correct property on the combo box is being set. I could have named the user control's property "George", and, as long as the logic returns baseComboBox.Items, it will work. Of course, that might confuse any programmer who has to work with the user control!  lol.

Answer (score 0):

Defining Set as a ***simple baseComboBox.Items = value;*** is impossible because **baseComboBox.Items** is defined as **ReadOnly**.
The problem is also the lack of a defined editor for such a collection.

Therefore, you should add the editor definition and instead of trying to replace the collection as one object - use **AddRange**:

```
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, " +
        "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
        typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items
    {
        get
        {
            return baseComboBox.Items;
        }
        set
        {
            baseComboBox.Items.Clear();
            baseComboBox.Items.AddRange(value.Cast<object>().ToArray());
        }
    }
```