# 'MyUserControls.ComboBox1' does not contain definition for 'ItemsSource'

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, user-controls, blend

I have created a User Control Library in MS's Blend for use with a WPF C# project. This is my first attempt using Blend to create a User Control, and I am having trouble implementing it.

The problem I have is with my `ComboBox`. When I go to code behind, I cannot access or set the `ComboBox1.ItemsSource` or any other specific properties.
Just in case it was my ComboBox that was causing the problem, I created a Chrome template `ComboBox`, and tried that, but I got the same result.

**Ultimate Goal:** This as a functional `ComboBox`

[image]

Do I need to add a reference, access the `ItemsPresenter` in another way or is there something else I should be doing to make it a 'fully-functional' `ComboBox`, like applying my template to a standard `ComboBox` or should it work the way it is?

I have researched this, but can't find anything past creating the `ComboBox`([this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273078(v=vs.100).aspx),[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273074(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341409(v=expression.40).aspx)). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004541/usercontrol-contains-a-combobox-but-the-items-set-at-design-time-are-not-in-the), but I am unsure if it is relevant, but It's not working for me.

["To instantiate the user control in another document"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294992.aspx#Anchor_1) looked promising, but didn't help. Neither did [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx#Anchor_0).

`MainWindow.xaml`

(MyComboBox is a standard 'Chrome' `ComboBox` placed in a User Control in Blend)

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MyUserControls="clr-namespace:MyUserControls;assembly=MyUserControls"
    x:Name="Window" x:Class="UserControlTester.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="252.584" Width="557">
<Grid >
    <MyUserControls:MyComboBox  x:Name="ComboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,201.713,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Tester program `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace UserControlTester
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<string> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //add stuff to drives...
        ComboBox1.ItemsSource = items; //Error on ItemsSource "'MyUserControls.ComboBox1' does not contain a definition for 'ItemsSource'..."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`? How is `ComboBox1.ItemsSource`? You may want to share your xaml.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, `ComboBox1.ItemsSource` gives the error.

Comment: You may have a trouble when the control is located in template. Any way, providing a xaml sample snippet here will lead more precise answers, I guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the control is located in template"?

Comment: Not matter as you have no template. I doubt `MyComboBox` has a base class that has `ItemsSource`. Code of `MyComboBox`?

Comment: It's 235 lines (with triggers and animation); It's just the standard Chrome combo box in a user control. I haven't touched it.

Comment: Make sure `public class MyComboBox : ComboBox { ... }`. If just a `ComboBox` is located in a `UserControl`, the control has naturally no `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're conflating the concepts of `UserControl` and **Custom Control**, which are 2 completely different concepts in WPF, and must be applied in different use cases. I see a lot of people incurring into this mistake, so I'll shed some light to it:

- A `UserControl` is a class that derives from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`, and represents a "widget" made by composing other controls together. The typical use case is as a "view" for a certain Model or ViewModel, for example a `PersonDataView` UserControl, which contains TextBoxes and Labels for the LastName, FirstName, and Age properties of a Person object. `UserControl`s are typically defined by a XAML file + a code behind file. The code and the XAML are coupled together, and the code will operate on the elements declared in XAML.
- A *Custom Control* is a class that inherits from any WPF control class (such as `ComboBox`, `TextBox`, etc, or even `Control`, `FrameworkElement` or `UIElement`) and adds **functionality** (as opposed to modifying or adding visual appearance, which must be done via [Styling and Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms745683(v=vs.100).aspx)). The typical use case is precisely to add functionality to an existing Control (such as for example, adding numbers to a `TickBar`), or to create a completely custom visual element that cannot be achieved either by composing nor customizing existing controls (for example a LookupBox, which allows keyboard-based searching of items in a list). A Custom Control is typically defined by a code-only class (no XAML) and then it's visual tree is defined by a `ControlTemplate` and assigned to the control via a `Style`. The code is decoupled from the XAML and typically you will use `Template.FindName()` if you need to access elements defined in the `ControlTemplate`.

In your case, I assume you just intend to change the existing `ComboBox`'s **visual appearance**, therefore I would simply create a `ControlTemplate` for the ComboBox, which does not need a custom control, at all.

I strongly suggest you read [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Comment: I have read that, and many others. But I will read it again. I thought it was a user control, because I created a User Control Lib, and added a User Control (xaml) I haven't seen the words 'Custom Control' in Blend!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `MyComboBox` is not actually a `ComboBox`.

Possible solutions:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox { ... }
```

This way it is difficult to extend xaml.

Other:

```
public class MyComboBox : UserControl {
  public ItemsSource ItemsSource {
    get { return this.ComboBox1.ItemsSource; }
    set { this.ComboBox1.ItemsSource = value; }
  }
}
```

Not scalable but straightforward (not intended to use in xaml). Use `DependencyProperty` for xaml-use.

Still, simply:

```
this.ComboBox1.InnterComboBox.ItemsSource = ...
```

Comment: `not intended to use in xaml` means that this should NOT be done in WPF.

Comment: From the beginning, you should not set `ItemsSource` in CB. This is just a rough workaround.

Comment: `this.ComboBox1.InnterComboBox.ItemsSource = ...` - bad practice.

Comment: Alright, stick to MVVM. This is just the fastest way to solve the error. These ugly ways will tell the excellence of MVVM.

Comment: your solution does not solve the OP's underlying problem, which is the fact that they incorrectly created a custom class when they needed something else.

Comment: Question is the source of error... you should respect the way n00dles is currently on. I COMPLETELY AGREE with your answer in the long run.